# How to repair wamp server without re-installing?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, wamp, wampserver

**After making changes in php.ini by uncommenting**

```
    extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**My Windows-8 system got shutdown due to power failure and later i use to get this error when i try to start wamp server**

[image: Aestan tray menu missing]

**Later visiting some link i added the below code to wampmanager.ini file as it was empty**

[image]

**Now the first error got fixed and now throwing this error mentioned below:**

[image]

**Later i also installed visual c++ 2008 to fix this error but unsuccessful. I have many important databases which i have not taken back up also. I am trying to repair this wamp server without re-installing. Can anybody please assist me with this.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have a backup of your php.ini?

Comment: Yes i have @ChristianMark

Comment: Have you tried replacing the php.ini file with the old php.ini file?

Comment: I am sorry, i have the earlier php version backup but not the latest apache version : 2.4.4 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This document may help you [How to uninstall WAMPServer without actually uninstalling it](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

The idea is that you uninstall your current version without actually running the unninstall and without actually deleting any files from your existing install.

You then rename the current wamp folder and then install the same version of wamp, make sure it works, and then copy all your sites and databases to the new installed wamp. If you install exactly the version of WAMP you have currently then you can copy the whole of the  .../mysqlx.y.z/data folder and all you databases and users should be there on the new install.

This gets over whatever damage was done to your existing install. You may need to edit the php.ini and httpd.conf to match your existing configuration. I suggest you do not do a straight copy of either of these files as that may just get you to where you are now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw the link provided, its very painful to follow each steps carefully. I was thinking to rename the installed wamp folder and try to install the wamp server again in the same directory. If i take the back up which is located in   C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data and paste the same in to the new one, will that solve my problem?

Comment: Thats basically what the doc suggests but without re-installing over the existing folder.

Comment: I ran `reinstall all services` from the wamp server tray `tools` menu and it worked. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 32):

go to the wamp/scripts folder
open console 
run:
`php refresh.php`

this should recreate wampmanager.ini

(requires wampmanager.tpl file in wamp folder.
taken from http://sourceforge.net/p/wampserver/feature-requests/10/#750b)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by installing wamp again into the same directory by renaming the older wamp. I just replaced wampmanager.ini file of new to the old one. Earlier it was just a little piece of code i pasted in wampmanager.ini file. But now it is a big one which fixed this issue. Thanks a lot for you guys, your suggestions saved my time. I did not change anything with php.ini also.

Answer (score 2):

1. Backup all YOUR databases in SQL format and store the backups somewhere safe.
2. Stop All Services.
3. Remove the Apache Service.
4. Remove the MySQL Service.
5. Exit WAMPServer.
6. Rename your current \wamp folder to \wamp_old (This is your backup. DONT FORGET THIS STEP)

To all intents and purpose, you have uninstalled WAMPServer now.
7. Download and Install the new WAMPServer version
(32bit is recommended, 64bit is only for geeks and 64bit PHP is not yet fully converted to 64bit)

8. Change NOTHING! Check it works in its out of the box state.

Clear your browser cache ( CTRL+F5 ) to avoid any funnies with cached content.
Run localhost
Run phpMyAdmin (If asked for a Username and password; username = root / password = (nothing, leave this blank)
Run \wamp\www\testmysql.php. you will need to edit the file and change the "mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '')"

9. If you want to bring some/all of your old versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL into the new WAMPServer
   (Remember, one of the big advantages in WAMPServer is the ability to switch between versions of Apache/PHP and MySQL)

Apache: copy \wamp_old\bin\apache\apachex.y.z folder to \wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z

PHP: copy \wamp_old\bin\php\phpx.y.z folder to \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z

MYSQL: copy \wamp_old\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z folder to \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z

10. To tell WAMPServer about the old version of Apache/PHP/MySQL you just copied across run a "refresh",
    right click the wampmanager icon -> Refresh
    Give it a few seconds to go find all the new versions.
11. Compare your old configs with the new configs, move over any of your local change/requirements.
    Remember, config parameters change between versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL !
    Make sure your old changes are still required, valid, legal. ( Check the upgrade notes provided by all 3 software providers )
12. If it all goes horribly wrong. Check the bottom of this Doc to see how to unwind all these changes easily if you get problems.

[help you](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. I am working with WAMP 2.5 version. The content of "wampmanager.ini" is OK but it's possible that the php path is wrong. Check folders of section [StartupAction], in my case my php version is "php5.5.12". Surely the error message "The directory name is invalid" was for this.

Answer (score 1):

In win10 you can just right click on the wampmanager.ini file in the root and select Restore Previous Version, then just choose one from a few days ago when it worked.

Comment: Might also need to do it with C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf\httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

i have similair issue in the morning and searched SO and other forums but none of the solution worked for me.

It was

> syntax error on line number 561 (due to MariaDB)

After checking all wamp installation for MariaDB, i find out that file at root: `wampmanager.conf` contain lines about MariaDB. **I removed all of those and then restarted wamp**. It worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the wamp folder, you can just add a 1 or 0 to somehing like wamp641 then
2. re-install wamp server
   3.copy paste the mysql and project folders from Bin and WWW respectively from the renamed wamp folder to the newly created folder after installation so that you dont loose any database and project files from your previous projects.
   4 start your wamp and it should work well.