# WAMP server startup error: "No tray icon was specified"

Tags: wampserver

I get an error when I try to load WAMP Server:

> The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 0; [EParseError] No tray icon was specified. Please assign a tray icon by using on the of the Trayicon directives in the [Config] section.

What am I supposed to do? It won't load WAMPServer.

Comment: Have you checked that you have all the required Microsoft C++ runtime libraries? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011072/msvcr110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/26013219#26013219

Comment: Jessé Catrinck's answer was the solution for me, however I had to execute `refresh.php` with `php.exe` found in **php5.6.40**. Any other version of php resulted in errors and wampmanager.ini would not be rebuilt. Here is the full command I ran in Command Prompt with administrative privileges:
`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.40\php.exe C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php`

Answer (score 87):

- Go to the wamp/scripts folder
- Open console
- run: `php refresh.php`

This should recreate wampmanager.ini
(requires wampmanager.tpl file in wamp folder.

Taken from http://sourceforge.net/p/wampserver/feature-requests/10/#750b)

**Tested only in wampserver 2.4.**

**Working wampserver 3.2.3 as well**

Answered in:
[How to repair wamp server without re-installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213915/how-to-repair-wamp-server-without-re-installing#answer-31411705)

Comment: This is 2018, and this still worked for me. Thanks for this.

Comment: It works, it really woks! In Windows I went to "scripts" but "php.exe" is in another directory, so I wrote `C:\WAMP\scripts> ..\bin\php\php7.0.0\php.exe refresh.php` . After this I noticed that I lost "php.ini", I don't know if it was lost since before the problem, so I made a copy of "php.ini-development" in "bin\php\php7.0.0", renamed it "php.ini" and moved it to "bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin".

Comment: This definitely works. Just to be sure, run cmd as administrator.

Comment: Working for me, thanks man save my work, thanks a lot.

Comment: Working on 3.2.3 as well

Comment: Worked on WAMP 3.3.0

Answer (score 22):

Same thing happened to me after a Windows update. Some of the solutions above haven't worked for me (as of 2017) but here's what solved it without having to reinstall Wamp.

Head over to [WampServer's repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/), scroll down to "Tools" and download **wampmanager.ini repair**. Run the .exe, open wampini_repair.bat, and you're golden!

Comment: It's 2021, this worked like a charm. Had the same issue after a Windows update and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Worked successfully November 2022. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I also encountered the same error some-times ago and the fix was so simple.

Take note of the wamp server version you installed.

The fix:

1. Rename the current wamp folder under C:/wamp to wamp2
2. Install a new instance of the same wamp on the C: drive
3. Copy the wampmanager INI file from the new installation (C:/wamp) into the old folder (C:/wamp2)
4. Delete the new wamp folder
5. Rename the old folder from wamp2 to wamp
6. Startup your wamp server, and see the magic.

Remember to say thanks !

Answer (score 10):

The problem is in wampmanager.ini.
Check if the above file is empty, if so adding the following code will work

```
[Config]
ImageList=images_off.bmp
ServiceCheckInterval=1
ServiceGlyphRunning=13
ServiceGlyphPaused=14
ServiceGlyphStopped=15
TrayIconAllRunning=16
TrayIconSomeRunning=17
TrayIconNoneRunning=18
ID={wampserver}
AboutHeader=WAMP5
AboutVersion=Version 2.2

[AboutText]
WampServer Version 2.2

Maintainer / Upgrade / Roadmap by Herve Leclerc (herve.leclerc@alterway.fr)

Powered by Alter Way [www.alterway.fr]

Sources are available at SourceForge

[www.wampserver.com]

[Services]
Name: wampapache
Name: wampmysqld

[Messages]
AllRunningHint=WAMP5 - All services running - server Offline
SomeRunningHint=WAMP5 - %n of %t services running - server Offline
NoneRunningHint=WAMP5 - None of %t services running - server Offline

[StartupAction]
Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php-win.exe";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "c:/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
```

Add the correct path to php-win.exe. (change the php5.5.12 to your installed version)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install the same version of WAMP to a with the same folder structure to a different partition ( if you don't have an extra partition use external drive). For example, if your current WAMP, which causes you the error is in `C:/wamp64`, install the duplicate in `D:/wamp64`.

After that copying process, the content of the `wampmanager.ini` from the new installation and replace to `wampmanager.ini` of the old installation ( open the file with *Notepad*, delete the existing stuff and replace it with the copied content).

Then replace the drive letter with the old drive letter (i.e `D:/wamp64` with `C:/wamp64` ) and save the file. ( you will have two lines to change this letter).

That is it. You are ready and good to go.

Enjoy!!

Tested with wamp64 version 3.0 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First take the backup of all the folders from c:\wamp folder then reinstall wamp. 
Copy the files named wampmanager.exe and wampmanager.conf from c:\wamp files (Files from Backup) to the folder c:\wamp you will be asked to replace the existing files, do it. Then Start WAMP Server. The problem is fixed.

If you do it, your project files will not lose.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by going into the wamp64 folder and simply running wampmanager.ini.repair . This opened a version of wamp where only 2 of 3 services were running, but I exited out of that and ran wamp again as administrator, and it started working.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the similar issue and got the fix. You just have to search for the file name wampmanager.ini in the WAMP server installation and replace the file content with the following content. Be sure to put the correct directory path.

```
[Config]
ImageList=images_off.bmp
ServiceCheckInterval=1
ServiceGlyphRunning=13
ServiceGlyphPaused=14
ServiceGlyphStopped=15
TrayIconAllRunning=16
TrayIconSomeRunning=17
TrayIconNoneRunning=18
ID={wampserver}
AboutHeader=WAMP5
AboutVersion=Version 2.2

[AboutText]
WampServer Version 2.2

Maintainer / Upgrade / Roadmap by Herve Leclerc (herve.leclerc@alterway.fr)

Powered by Alter Way [www.alterway.fr]

Sources are available at SourceForge

[www.wampserver.com]

[Services]
Name: wampapache
Name: wampmysqld

[Messages]
AllRunningHint=WAMP5 - All services running - server Offline
SomeRunningHint=WAMP5 - %n of %t services running - server Offline
NoneRunningHint=WAMP5 - None of %t services running - server Offline

[StartupAction]
Action: run; FileName: "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php-win.exe";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "c:/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
```