# Wamp: The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 24

Tags: wamp, wampserver

How can I start the wamp server on windows 7 using wamp version 2.4?

Following is the error message I get:

> The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 24:
>   [EParseError][config] section directive "ImageList" already specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ISSUE**

You have a duplicate entry on `C:\wamp\wampmanager.ini`

`ImageList=images_off.bmp` or something like that.

**FIX**

Remove one of them (probably line 24)

Comment: wamp The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 1243: [EParseError] parameter "service" specific an unknown  service

Comment: There is no point editing wampmanager.ini as it is rebuilt each time you run WAMPServer.

Answer (score 14):

**Error:**

> The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 7;
> [EParseError] No tray icon was specified. Please assign a tray icon by
> using on the of the Tray icon directives in the [Config] section.

**Caused by:**
Computer abruptly shutting down while server is running

**Fix:**
• Go to the wamp/scripts folder
• Open console/cmd as admin
• run: *php refresh.php*
• Done!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30159777)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have php in your system environment settings
then go to the wamp/scripts folder
open console
run:

```
php refresh.php
```

[answer from here solved my issue, referenced above info from this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31411705/5157349)

Comment: nice! Have no idea what happened, suddenly I had an error about an unclosed '"' but this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have been playing with `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl`

**Never play with `wampmanager.tpl` unless you have taken a copy first!**

WAMPServer rebuilds `\wamp\wampmanager.ini` using a script that uses `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl` among other files as input, **each time you start WAMPServer** or when you use the wampmanager menus and click `refresh`.

So to fix your problem edit of wampmanager.tpl to remove the duplicated line and then do:

```
rightclick wampmanager icon -> refresh
```

Or just exit wampmanager and restart it.

to rebuild the `\wamp\wampmanager.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of your `Wampmanager.ini` file in your wamp installation directory (in my case it is `c:\Wamp64`). Then rename it or move it to some other folder.
Get the `wampmanager.ini` from a new installation or any similar installation if you already have, then paste it in the same path. It will work like charm. This may change any of the settings you had earlier but it will make your wamp working without reinstalling it.

- [Wamp Manager folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVFuN.png)
- [Wamp Manager configuration file in CMD prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z9uh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that this error shows up after **initial** install of the current version 3.2.6 found on [aviatechno](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) (without being able to tamper with any installed configuration file, the .ini in the installation is broken). It reports an error with line 27: `WAMPMARIADBOFF`.

```
[Services]
Name: APACHESERVICE
WAMPMARIADBOFFName: MARIADBSERVICE
WAMPMYSQLOFFName: MYSQLSERVICE
```

Use the new ini repair tool you can find [on the aviatechno website](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=es&prerequis=afficher)

which corrects the lines in the ini file as:

```
[Services]
Name: wampapache
Name: wampmysqld
Name: wampmariadb
...
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmariadb; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
```

## Only do this on new installs

Even after that wampserver does not start or does not start the services. To repair: stop the background process AeTrayMenu, head over to the folder `c:\wamp64` removing its content and reinstall.

This did the trick for me.